# Are record locks, gap locks, Next-key locks, Insert Intention Locks and AUTO-INC Locks the part of Intention Locks?

Tags: mysql, locks

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html) of MySQL all the types of the locking are the different types of locks. But all of them use FOR SHARE or FOR UPDATE instruction as the Intention Locks. So I can't understand are the record locks, gap locks, Next-key locks, Insert Intention Locks and AUTO-INC Locks the part of Intention Locks or this is the absolutely different types of locks but with the same syntax

Comment: how did you get this notion? and the answer is clearly no

Comment: For example there is an example of record lock looks like SELECT c1 FROM t WHERE c1 = 10 FOR UPDATE; in the documentation in the section Record Locks

Comment: FOR update will perform a row lock for the selected rows, but if you have to many rows you get a table lock, this has nothing to do with itentional locks

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but to clarify that documentation: those locks are not something you choose directly. You tell MySQL your isolation level, write your query (maybe specifying `for update/share`) and MySQL picks the correct *internal* locks itself to ensure proper behaviour. These details are "just" a technical documentation, you can use MySQL absolutely correctly without ever hearing about next key locks.

Comment: hi @Solarflare - So, this documentation is ONLY there to "know what goes on behind the scenes" and from there to know what level of isolation suits us, ¿right?

Comment: @Daniel It's vice versa. You pick the isolation based on your requirements. That behaviour is standardized, and that's where you start and what you need to know. It's like driving a car. Left paddle, right paddle, one in the middle, you know how it works on one car, you know how it works for other cars. If you want to know how the implementation of the break in a mercedes differs from a ford, if you need to fix it, if you want to know why for the same force with your leg, the break on a mercedes reacts faster/slower than on a ford, you need to read the technical manual (and then some more).

Comment: great @Solarflare excellent analogy, now I understand, thanks +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are mixing up intention locks with the different type of actual locks!

As mysql documentation you linked in your question says (emphasis is mine):

> Intention locks are **table-level locks** that **indicate** which type of lock (shared or exclusive) a transaction requires **later** for a row in a table.

All the other locks you listed are actual locks used when you execute insert, update or delete statements.

Comment: hi @Shadow excellent, but, for there to be a record lock/gap lock/next-key lock/insert intention lock/AUTO-INC lock FIRST IT SETS an intention lock in the table, right?

Comment: ... i.e., they are "related" to the intention lock